Sampling a vector of size $n$ which sums to $k$ sequentially
Suppose I want to sample a vector $X$ such that every entry is sampled from some distribution $p$ and all entries sum to $k$ (the entries are not independent).
I thought I can simply sample $X_1$ from $p$ truncated at $k$, then $X_2$ from $p$ truncated at $k-X_1$ etc. With
$$p(X_1, \ldots, X_n\mid k)=p(X_1\mid k)p(X_2\mid X_1, k)...p(X_n, \mid X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}, k)$$
But the process I described seems to bias the first entries to be larger?
